# Django rest framework signup function authentication failure problem

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, jwt

everyone,
Now I am going to build django rest framework backend.
And I am going to use JWT authentication.
So I have set rest_framework like that:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
}
```

But when I call signup api, it gives me 401 unauthorized error. Because signup function cannot include any jwt token, it is right. But if so, anybody never can call signup and login api.
When I remove 'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated' from 'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES', the api works well.
I am going to allow only authorized users call other apis except signup and login api.
But if I set 'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated', signup and login api can't be called.
Front-End is React and in React code, I set token to axios header after login.
Is there any setting to solve this problem in django? Please help me, if you know any experience with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
It is simple.
You can use permission decorator like @permission_classes((AllowAny, )).
So if you want allow any users the signup api, you can write like that:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((AllowAny, ))
def signup(request):
   dosomething
```

If you want restrict permission, you can write like that:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated))
def api_name(request):
    something
```